# Squish points to within plot axes in R plot

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am making a volcano plot in R. I have a huge range of pvalues and log2fold changes. I set an xlim and ylim because I want to focus in on the central region of the plot. However, naturally setting my limits excludes some of my data. I would like to have the data outside of my axes limits displayed at my limits. So for example, a fold change of 4 would be displayed as a point just outside of my xlim of 2.

```
with(mydata, plot(ExpLogRatio, -log10(Expr_p_value), pch=20, main = "Volcano Plot",xlim=c(-2,2),ylim=c(0,40)))
```

this works but cuts out some of my datapoints (those with fold change above 2 and less than -2 and with pvalue of less than -log10(40)

Comment: Can you please provide sample data? Perhaps `dput(head(mydata,n=10))` (or as many rows and columns as required to *sufficiently* get the point across without flooding the question/screen).

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, I'd just use `pmin` and `pmax` to limit your values, e.g.:

```
values = seq(-3, 3, len=21)
pmin(pmax(values, -2), 2)
```

gives back:

```
 [1] -2.0 -2.0 -2.0 -2.0 -1.8 -1.5 -1.2 -0.9 -0.6 -0.3  0.0  0.3  0.6  0.9  1.2
[16]  1.5  1.8  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
```

i.e. it's limited values to the range (-2, +2).

applying this to your data, you'd do something like:

```
with(mydata, {
  lratio <- pmin(pmax(ExpLogRatio, -2.1), 2.1)
  pch <- ifelse(ExpLogRatio == lratio, 20, 4)
  plot(lratio, -log10(Expr_p_value), pch=pch, ylim=c(0, 40))
})
```

you'll probably want to set `xlab` and `main` to set titles, but I've not included that to keep the answer tidier.  also extending this to the y-axis would obviously be easy

note I've also changed the plotting point style to indicate which points were truncated